# Get username of current logged-in user of joomla using external php script

Tags: php, joomla2.5

```
    <?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/mainpage' )); //mainpage is my joomla folder.

define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

 $user =& JFactory::getUser();
  $_SESSION['username'] = $user->get('name'); 
  if ($user->get('guest') == 1) {echo"blabla";} else { echo "Hi ".$_SESSION['username']."! Welcome to our great website!";}
?>
```

This will result blabla in the browser, I actually want to have the 'Hi "MyName" Welcome to our great website!'. I create this file outside joomla folder.. the name of joomla folder is "mainpage". the $_SESSION['username'] is empty. I need to get current joomla username or name..

Please Help...

Thanks,

Leo

Comment: I've not used Joomla but try adding `session_start();`  at the top of the script (after <?php but before the define)?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 

    //defined('_JEXEC') or die;
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
    define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/' )); //mainpage is my joomla folder.

    define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
    $mainframe->initialise();
    $session =& JFactory::getUser();
    echo 'Welcome : ' . $session->get( 'name', 'empty' ). ',';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you even use an external php script. You can include the code within your template (or wherever you need it) just fine.

As for why it fails: You create your very own instance of the application within your script. Outside the scope of Joomla, like if it is a separate installation. In this separate "Joomla", there is of course no user logged in, as the user logged in to your regular Joomla site.

What exactly are you trying to achieve?